# Tremolo claw screws don't adjust bridge angle on Floyd Rose

Tags: bridge

Here is my bridge and as you can see it's way forward! 
[image: Bridge angle]

And here is my back of my guitar: 
[image: Tremolo Claw]

I tried screwing claw screws all the way in but the bridge stay the same, so what am I doing wrong here? 
Here is how I get to this point: 
I bought this guitar secondhand and the bridge was sitting parallel to the body, but I found out the intonation was not right, so I searched about it and played with saddles but I ruin everything and detune my guitar to start over but I got here and have no idea what should I do. Unfortunately because of the lock down I can't go out and hand my guitar to a profession

Comment: What gauge strings? What tuning?

Comment: If it was ok before, list everything you did, and show that list. The guitar ***must*** be in tune while you do some of these adjustments

Comment: You must have done more than 'play with saddles'. Have you re-tuned it to the correct pitch? It's possible the tuning is too high, causing this problem.

Comment: @Tim Yep, but the thing is it took maybe 30 or more tries to get it the perfect pitch (I started from low E to high E)